# Forcing freeradius to use 802.1x-2010

Tags: troubleshooting, radius, freeradius, wpa, 802.1x

I am trying to troubleshoot a remote problem, where a piece of hardware is unable to connect using enterprise WPA. From the remote logs, it seems that the network is using 802.1X-2010, while the hardware device may only be able to support 802.1X-2004.

To be able to troubleshoot the problem locally, I need to create a networking setup where the local network is running with a comparable configuration. I do not have access to anything more advanced than freeradius, so I am trying to configure this to run in only 802.1X-2010 mode. I am however unable to find any information on how to force this setting for freeradius.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for configuring freeradius to emit EAP frames of version 3 only? Or alternatively, a different network stack which can be configured to run in only this mode?

Comment: Can you share some excerpts of the logs/debug output that you're seeing? (redact if you need to). AFAIK the latest EAP standard doesn't break anything from the old one, it just adds some things like MACSEC etc. (which can be a huge bxtch to configure properly and not super commonly used yet, so I have some doubts that it's a compatibility thing.) The `-X` flag should run freeradius in debug mode for you to see the actual message exchange, and check what debug options you have for your authenticator/supplicant as well. (hostapd/wpasupplicant use`-dd` for max verbosity, if that's relevant.)